# What does the program Samsung Kies light do?

Tags: samsung-kies

I use Samsung kies for my Galaxy S1 and I also installed Kies Light but I don't understand what it does. I would like the function the send SMS from my computer, can it do that or what does it do?

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. Does nobody want to know what this program does? I have used a Galaxy 3 for nearly a year, and still cannot find sufficient info about it. I really want to know, too.

Comment: There's not enough information here. Is this a variant from Samsung? Is this a third-party app?

Comment: I know there has been at least one question here about sending SMS by using a connected computer. Have you tried searching here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source: [Samsung FAQs: Cell Phones: What is Kies Lite mode, and what can I do when using it?](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/SupportOwnersFAQPopup.do?faq_id=FAQ00052685&fm_seq=61255)

> Kies Lite mode launches the application with a reduced set of features. This uses fewer system resources and lets some key features of Kies run more efficiently. Using Kies Lite mode, you can access and use these features more quickly: Firmware Upgrade, Sync Data, Backup, and Restore.
>
> You can switch to Kies Lite mode by clicking Kies Lite Mode Icon in the top-right corner of the screen. If you switch to Kies Lite and you close the application, Kies will open in Lite mode next time you run the application. To switch back to "normal" Kies mode, simply click the icon again.
>
> Or open Kies in Lite mode by double-clicking Kies Lite Icon on your Windows® desktop.

So it would seem that the functionality is limited to: Firmware Upgrade, Sync Data, Backup, and Restore.

Answer (score 1):

Kies for Samsung phones and tablets is more or less similar to what iTunes is for iPhones, iPods, and iPads.

It allows you to synchronize your music and video collections, synchronize your schedule and contacts from Outlook or Yahoo, perform and restore backups, and perform updates to the Android OS.

Kies Light is just an alternate, somewhat less featureful, GUI for Kies

It doesn't allow for remote control capabilities.  For that, you want another app, such as [Airdroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid).

Comment: The question was about "Kies Light", not Kies.

Comment: @AlEverett - Kies Lite is Kies, just run using a more minimalist GUI.

Comment: @Compro01 So that should be pointed out in the answer, then.